# Total curvature of non planar curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Suppose a simple closed curve $\gamma$ is drawn on a curved surface. The total curvature of the curve $\oint_\gamma \kappa(s)ds$ is larger than $2\pi$ (apparently this is called Fenchel's theorem).

I imagine this quantity could be related, by some kind of Stokes theorem, to an integral over the domain of the surface which has $\gamma$ as its boundary. Is that true?

Namely, let $S$ be such that $\gamma=\partial S$. Does there exist a function $f$ on the surface such that 
$$ \oint_\gamma \kappa(s)ds=\int_S f(x)dx \text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Gauss-Bonnet Theorem relates the integral of the *geodesic curvature* (which is the curvature of the curve as viewed by an inhabitant of the surface) to the integral of Gaussian curvature over the region bounded by the curve.

I interpreted your question to be for a surface sitting in $\Bbb R^3$, say, and for $\kappa$ to represent the curvature of the curve as a curve in $\Bbb R^3$. In that case, there is no relation to anything depending just on the surface.

**COMMENT**: Fenchel's Theorem actually says the total curvature is *at least* $2\pi$, with $2\pi$ occurring *if and only if* the curve is a convex planar curve. (I see your title specified your curve wasn't planar, so this is not literally a correction.)

Comment: You interpreted the question correctly, thanks. Can the Gauss-Bonnet theorem be interpreted as a Stokes theorem?

Comment: Yes, one can prove Gauss-Bonnet using Stokes's Theorem, along with its generalizations to higher dimensions. The usual undergraduate treatment of curves and surfaces avoids differential forms, which are the most powerful way to deal with Stokes's Theorem in general.

Comment: P.S. @thedude: If you're studying this stuff, you might want to check out my (free) text on curves and surfaces, linked in my profile.

Comment: I did read some of it, to my great advantage, but at some points my confusion was too great ;)

Comment: Oh, cool. Well, feel free to ask more questions if you're interested .... Have you studied multivariable calculus and some linear algebra yet?

Comment: Since you mentioned, I have just posted [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816458/holonomy-and-curvature-on-a-surface) to which I would appreciate an answer...