# Holonomy and curvature on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, holonomy

I have read in a few places that the change in direction a vector experiences when parallel transported along a closed circuit $\partial D$ (holonomy) is equal to the surface integral of the gaussian curvature inside the circuit, $\iint_D K dS=\Delta\phi(\partial D)$.

An example I understand is this: take a vector on the north pole, transport down to the equator, go around a quarter circle, go back to the north pole. This will give $\Delta\phi=\pi/2$. The integral of the curvature equals 1/8 of the area of the sphere, so also $\pi/2$. Fine.

However, what if I do almost the same thing, but don't go all the way down to the equator? I go down some amount, then go around a quarter circle along a fixed latitude and go back. Won't the angle still be $\pi/2$ in this case? But the area is smaller...

Also, books notice that this theorem only holds when the domain $D$ lies `in an orthogonal parametrization` or `is covered by a single orhonormal frame`. I am not sure what this means and how restrictive it is.

Comment: The small quarter-circle is no longer a geodesic, so the vector will change its angle of the lines of longitude when parallel transported along it.

Comment: Indeed, the very theorem I mention implies that if I go all around with a fixed latitude there will be non-zero holonomy. But I definitely have trouble "seeing" this. It "feels" that the vector should always point in the direction of the lines of longitude...

Comment: How does it "feel" like that? See in particular the discussion in Examples 3 (pp. 68-69) and the Remark (p. 71) of my text. Since the tangent vector to a latitude circle at $u=u_0<\pi/2$, say, has covariant derivative pointing "up" the sphere, the vector field must rotate clockwise to stay parallel. The same applies to the vectors pointing along the longitudes. This lessens the net rotation angle in your scenario so that it will in fact be less than $\pi/2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok, and I suppose the fact that transporting along the equator produces no holonomy has to do with that "orthogonal frames" business? How is that?

Comment: No, the equator is a geodesic.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know, but if I transport a full cycle close to the equator I will have $\int K dS$ close to $2\pi$. Is this equal to the holonomy angle?

Comment: Aha ... So the truth is that we do the holonomy angle mod $2\pi$ ... So the holonomy angle becomes $0$ ... which is right for the geodesic. (This gets discussed a bit in section 1 of Chapter 3 of my text.)